# Object as itemValue in <b:selectItems>

Tags: java, jsf, bootsfaces

I am beginner of java programmer and using Netbeans to generate the CRUD jsf from ERD and using bootsfaces to display my web UI but I don't know why it only show the value = "1" as below

Generated HTML as below, you can see the value is "1" & "2", but the correct value should be "CHI" & "COMP" if I am using b:selectOneMenu

```
<b:selectOneMenu id="deptUnitCode" value="#{isusVpnAppnMastController.selected.deptUnitCode}" label="#{bundle.CreateIsusVpnAppnMastLabel_deptUnitCode}" title="#{bundle.CreateIsusVpnAppnMastTitle_deptUnitCode}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateIsusVpnAppnMastRequiredMessage_deptUnitCode}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{deptUnitController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
</b:selectOneMenu>

<select id="j_idt13:deptUnitCodeInner" name="j_idt13:deptUnitCodeInner" class="form-control  bf-required" title="DeptUnitCode">
    <option data-label="---" value="">---</option>
    <option data-label="CHI - [CHI]" value="1">CHI - [CHI]</option>
    <option data-label="COMP - [COMP]" value="2">COMP - [COMP]</option>
</select>
```

But if I changed to f:selectOneMenu (i.e the native one) then the generated HTML is correct

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="deptUnitCode" value="#{isusVpnAppnMastController.selected.deptUnitCode}" label="#{bundle.CreateIsusVpnAppnMastLabel_deptUnitCode}" title="#{bundle.CreateIsusVpnAppnMastTitle_deptUnitCode}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateIsusVpnAppnMastRequiredMessage_deptUnitCode}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{deptUnitController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<select id="j_idt13:deptUnitCode" name="j_idt13:deptUnitCode" size="1" title="DeptUnitCode">    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="CHI">CHI - [CHI]</option>
    <option value="COMP">COMP - [COMP]</option>
</select>
```

Generated Java Controller as below, you can see the itemvalue is Object Class

```
public static SelectItem[] getSelectItems(List<?> entities, boolean selectOne) {
    int size = selectOne ? entities.size() + 1 : entities.size();
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[size];
    int i = 0;
    if (selectOne) {
        items[0] = new SelectItem("", "---");
        i++;
    }
    for (Object x : entities) {
        items[i++] = new SelectItem(x, x.toString());
    }
    return items;
}
```

Is it the bug show it in URL: https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/selectOneMenu.jsf

Any body having an idea to fix this rather than casting the Object x? 
Thank you for your attention

Comment: you could try specifying itemValue and itemLabel manually `<f:selectItems var="item" value="#{deptUnitController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" itemLabel="#{item}" itemValue="#{item}" />`.  could you give an example of an entity that might be passed in the List to getSelectItems?

Comment: <f:selectItems var="item" value="#{deptUnitController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" itemLabel="#{item}" itemValue="#{item}" /> 
I already tried this before but doesn't work

Comment: Value                   Label
======                =====
{empty string}      ---
CHI - [CHI]            CHI - [CHI]
COMP - [COMP]   COMP - [COMP]

But I don't know why the h:selectOneMenu (the Native one) can rendered correctly

Comment: not sure why it works with `h:selectOneMenu` because i would have expected it to use a converter if the `itemValue` is an object not a primitive.  you could try OmniFaces SelectItemsConverter http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter